# Cannot call method "setHtmlContent" in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a script that updates some resources on or company's intranet and I keep getting this error: "Cannot call method "setHtmlContent" of null." Can anyone point in the direction of why I am getting this error and how to fix it. Thank you for your help and here is the code:

```
var DOMAIN_NAME = 'website.com';
var SITE_NAME = 'intranet-site';
var DOC_FOLDERS = ['Intranet Docs/Admin Resources/Accounts Payable Resources',
                   'Intranet Docs/Admin Resources/Finance Resources',
                   'Intranet Docs/Admin Resources/HR Resources',
                   'Intranet Docs/Admin Resources/Payroll Resources',
                   'Intranet Docs/Admin Resources/SSP Resources',
                   'Intranet Docs/Admin Resources/Vehicle & Incident Resources',
                   'Intranet Docs/Directors Resources/Advisory Boards',  
                   'Intranet Docs/Comm and PR Resources/Logos and Graphics',
                   'Intranet Docs/Comm and PR Resources/Podcasts',
                   'Intranet Docs/Comm and PR Resources/Podcasts/Enrich Culture',
                   'Intranet Docs/Comm and PR Resources/Podcasts/Visionary Framework',
                   'Intranet Docs/Training and Program Resources/Base Camp',
                   'Intranet Docs/Training and Program Resources/Phone Greeting Training',
                   'Intranet Docs/Training and Program Resources/Safety Program'];
var WEB_PAGES = ['administration-resources/accounts-payable-resources',
                 'administration-resources/finance-forms',
                 'administration-resources/hr-forms-documents',
                 'administration-resources/payroll-resources',
                 'administration-resources/ssp-resources',
                 'administration-resources/vehicle-incident-resources',
                 'directors-resources/advisory-boards',
                 'communication-public-relation-tools/logos-and-graphics',
                 'communication-public-relation-tools/podcasts',
                 'communication-public-relation-tools/podcasts/enrich-culture',
                 'communication-public-relation-tools/podcasts/visionary-framework',
                 'training/base-camp',
                 'training/phone-greeting-training',
                 'training/safety-program'];

function updateAllIntranetResources() {

  for (var idx=0; idx<WEB_PAGES.length; ++idx) {
    var filesCnt = updateWebPage(WEB_PAGES[idx], DOC_FOLDERS[idx]);
  }

  return;
}

function updateWebPage(webpageName, folderPath) {
   Logger.log('Folder: ' + folderPath);
  var site = SitesApp.getSite(DOMAIN_NAME, SITE_NAME);
  var webpage = site.getChildByName(webpageName);

  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderPath);
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  // Begin building HTML for web page
  var htmlContent = "<h3>Resource List</h3><hr>";

  // Get file name and url of each file in folder and add to page
  var filesCnt = files.length;
  // Logger.log('Nbr of files: ' + filesCnt);
  if (filesCnt > 0) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < filesCnt; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
      var fileName = file.getName();
      var htmlContent = htmlContent + '<a href="' + fileUrl + '" target="_blank">' + fileName + '</a><hr>';
      // Logger.log('(' + i + ') fileUrl: ' + fileUrl);
      // Logger.log('fileName = ' + fileName);
    }
  }
  else {
    htmlContent += "<b>(no resources found)</b>";
  }

  webpage.setHtmlContent(htmlContent);

  return filesCnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in the line

```
 webpage.setHtmlContent(htmlContent);
```

The error occurs because `webpage` is null. 
Does it occur foe every web page or does it happen for only a few ? Also, note that the `webpageName` must be what you see in the URL of browser without the `http://sites.google.com/a/domain_name.com/site_name/`

It will be more useful if you can paste a log or execution transcript of the function's execution

Comment: This "webpage" object is embedded into the sidebar of the Google site, so it happens to all pages. The log seems to be too long to post, but I tried to run just the "updateWebPage" function and I get the error: **"Cannot find folder undefined."** on the line with 'var folder'. Does that help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the `webpage` object embedded in the sidebar. What I'm referring to is the variable called `webpage` in your code. 
Also, just running the `updateWebPage` function won't serve any purpose because you are not passing the two arguments it requires and therefore is bound to fail.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. What Logger.log (variable, function) would help best? Also, would just the end of the log suffice?

Comment: Just one instance of failing function would do. You can add a `break` statement in your for loop of `updateAllIntranetResources` to get the log of the first page

Comment: When I ran it with a `break` in the loop, it ran correctly. I removed the `break` and ran it again. Here is the last part of the log file, where it failed. `[13-08-29 09:49:13:313 PDT] Folder: Intranet Docs/Comm and PR Resources/Logos and Graphics
[13-08-29] <h3>Resource List</h3><hr><b>(no resources found)</b>
[13-08-29] Folder: Intranet Docs/Comm and PR Resources/Podcasts` execution log `[13-08-29] DocsList.getFolder([Intranet Docs/Comm and PR Resources/Podcasts]) [1.476 seconds]
[13-08-29] Folder.getFiles()
[13-08-29] Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot call method "setHtmlContent" of null`